# Create new class instance from existing class based on array

Tags: javascript, arrays, class

I have an array. I want to dynamically generate new class instances from an array.

```js
class Test{
  constructor(name){
    this.name = name;
  }
  getName(){
    return this.name;
  }
}

let myArray = [ "instance1", "instance2", "instance3" ];
```

I want a result like this:

```js
let myArray[i] = new Test;

myArray[i].getName();
```

Comment: Welcome!
Your class in not well-defined (`{}` missing from constructor, for one).
Look into [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).
Second value of `myArry` is not closed (with`'`).
Did you want only element `i` of the array to be an instance of the class, or all the elements of the array?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you just need to call [`Array.protype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the array, and as your callback function you use an arrow function to create a `new Test` from the array value.

```js
class Test {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

const names = ['instance1','instance2','instance3'];
const instances = names.map( name => new Test(name) );

console.log( instances[1].getName() ); // logs 'instance2'
```